# Integration of $dt/(1+t)$ from $0$ to $x$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm reading Stillwell's History of Mathematics book and came across this integration by Newton. I am wondering how the inner equation becomes $(1-t+t^2-t^3+\cdots)$.

While I can use a substitution method, it seems to me Newton approached this without applying substituion or knowing that $\dfrac d{du}\left(\ln u\right) = $ $\dfrac {u'}u$. Or did he?

The book also notes the Indians used the method of expanding a geometric series... I'm confused on this point as well.

Comment: For $|t|<1$, $\frac{1}{1+t} = 1- t+t^2-t^3 \cdots$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{1+t}$ can be written in the series form only within radius of convergence.See for $t=1$ the left side is $1/2$ but the right side diverges.(oscillates between $0$ and $1$.)So do not do such things without analyzing properly.The integral should have the value $\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{1+t}dt=\operatorname{ln}|1+x|$ provided $x\neq -1$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the geometric series of initial term $1$ and common ratio $-t$, and evaluate the sum of the first $n$ terms:

$$1-t+t^2-t^3+\cdots(-t)^{n-1}=\frac{1-(-t)^n}{1-(-t)}.$$

If $|t|<1$, you can let $n$ tend to infinity and get the identity

$$1-t+t^2-t^3+\cdots=\frac1{1+t}.$$